# When I am running a JBOSS 6.4 server in linux, I am getting Address already use error?

Tags: linux, ip, jboss

**Error**:`[org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.remoting.server.management: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.remoting.server.management: JBAS017112: Address already in use 127.0.0.1:9999`

This error I am getting, when I am trying to **re-starting** a JBOSS server 6.4.I checked by process manager and stopped that process, which one is running on **Port:9999**. But still I am getting same issue. Any one help me to rectify this problem.

Comment: `ss -ltp` please.  You may need to run under `sudo` to show the program information (`ss -p`).

Comment: Thank you!!. How can I stop particular port process? @sourcejedi

Answer (score 0):

`ss -ltp` please. You may need to run under `sudo` to show the program information (`ss -p`).

> How can I stop particular port process?

Server processes are expected to shut down cleanly on receipt of SIGTERM (terminate).  It is the default signal sent by `kill`.  Run kill with the numeric Process IDentifier as shown by `pid=` in the output of `ss`.

If there is a bug in your daemon or how it is set up, you may need to resort to SIGKILL: `kill -KILL`.  Often people write this as `kill -9 <pid>`.

It is recommended to troubleshoot any bugs in your daemon or how it is set up, if it is something you would like to work reliably.